# How to send private message in Telegram Bot using Telegraf.js Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf.js

I want to create a Telegram bot that can send message directly to users with their user_id saved in my db. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Shubham Mishra the only way that u have to send message with bot to user is if these user firstly started the bot, the your bot could send a message to user.

If u want to send message to any user u should use userbot, this is very helpfull to create one: https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon